# Is there a way to validate Strings parameters in spring boot? Issues with commas in strings

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I set up an api endpoint for a get request. The parameter is a String array where each String is a character separated list of numbers, like ["dr:1/2/3"]

```
@GetMapping("/getmapping")
public ResponseEntity<JsonNode> getRequest(String[] list) {
...
}
```

The problem is when I pass in a string like this ["dr:1,2,3"]

and the parameter gets automatically split into ["dr:1", "2", "3"]

Is there a way to stop the string from being split automatically?

I could use a different character to separate the numbers besides a comma and it would work, but then how would I validate if commas are being used so I can throw an appropriate error?

Comment: What is the purposed of "dr"?  If  you have control over the parameter, then perhaps the parameter type should be `Integer[]` instead of `String[]`?

Answer (score 1):

No what you want is some extremely custom behavior to be supported by spring.

What you can do is the following

```
@GetMapping("/getmapping")
public ResponseEntity<JsonNode> getRequest(String param) {
   String[] parts = param.split("/"); //Here you have the information as you want it to
...
}
```